# How to use angular material buttons with CSS grid

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, grid, responsive

I was trying to use Angular material with CSS grid system.

I have this code to the html that displays two buttons, one standard html button and the other uses the CSS class of Angular material:

```
<div class="grid">  
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary">ANGULAR BUTTON</button>
    <button>HTML BUTTON</button>
</div>
```

And this CSS class to the grid system:

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 2em;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(200px, auto);
    margin: 50px;
}
```

This appears to work fine, but when I resize the browser screen to a minor width value, the text in the Angular button doesnt fit into the button's container but the standard html button's text does. So I think the problem is in the class applied to the Angular button.

How can I solve this issue and get the standard html button's behaviour on the material button?

Images attached with the exposed behaviour.

[Result with full screen size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy4lB.png)

[Result with resized screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGeml.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to [Material Design guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons.html#buttons-flat-buttons) buttons were never considered to be multiline, but implementing this kind of behavior is not that complicated: add `white-space: initial;` to button style and you're ready to go. [See StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-1psbrz?file=app/app.component.css)